# Will a backup of all my files (including system reserved partition) be just as effective as a system image?

Tags: windows-8.1, backup

When creating system images I can only make exclusions for folders I don't want to backup. However when doing a normal file/folder backup, I can select just a few files/folders within a folder instead of making exclusions for every single file/folder I don't want to backup. 
That is why I would prefer to do a regular file backup as opposed to a system image.

However, is a file backup as effective as a system image at restoring a drive to a previous state from scratch? Would there be any hidden/protected system files/folders that may not be backed up in a file/folder backup?

NOTE: When performing the file/folder backup I would be booting up from a recovery drive on a USB flash drive and not from my Windows OS

Comment: Its worth considering windows image backup with 8.1 does one main backup and incremental, so in essence after the initial backup, its file based.

Comment: I don't use Windows to create the system image although when I used to, it always took the same amount of time to create a system image, regardless of whether it was the first time creating the system image or the second or the third. Based on that I thought that it always creates a system image from zero, rather than being incremental. But I'm not sure. Windows's system image creator pales in comparison to many others so I've stopped using it.

Answer (score 0):

About the ordinary files/data, the files backup is effective as a image backup.

But for the system backup (maybe including hidden/protected system or boot files), you'd better use image to backup.

Comment: That's what I think already but I'm looking for some more specific reasons to confirm that using a system image would be more effective in restoring from scratch than regular file backup while booting from a USB flash drive. Do you know of any specific folders/files that wouldn't be backed up? or any specific issues that may arise?